# how to avoid creating the loop with the fragment backstack

Tags: android, fragment, back-stack, fragment-backstack

I am trying to navigate between fragments like below:

```
Fragment A --> Fragment B --> Fragment C --> Fragment D
```

and the user can again navigate from `Fragment D --> Fragment A` 
like below:

```
Fragment D --> Fragment A --> Fragment B --> Fragment C --> Fragment D
```

in this case a loop is created on the back press key.How to manage this type of situation to avoid the loop of fragment on backpress.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation loop not a bad thing. Do not try to avoid it.

There is navigation pattern that could help you with this problem http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html